# Why size of void pointer is 4 on Windows 64-bit platform

Tags: c, windows, programming-languages, 32bit-64bit

I have the following program that prints 4. I am running this program on Windows 7 64-bit. Shouldn't it print 8 for 64-bit platform? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    printf("%d", sizeof(void*));
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the compiler?

Comment: Are you sure you're building a 64-bit binary?

Comment: what version of compiler u r using? if your compiler is 32 bit, it will use WOW64. and will behave like normal 32 bit process

Comment: Show your compiler invocation, please.

Comment: Recommend: Lessons on development of 64-bit C/C++ applications - http://www.viva64.com/en/l/

Comment: If you *were* using a 64-bit compiler, you'd have a different problem, because you can't properly print `sizeof`'s value using `%d`.

Answer (score 15):

When you use a compiled language such as C, the size of the pointer is not determined by the platform on which you are running your code: it depends only on the platform for which you have compiled your code.

Windows 7 64-bit can run code compiled for 32-bit platforms. Judging by the output of your program, it appears that your code has been compiled for Win-32.

In Visual Studio 2010, to to the properties page of your C/C++ project, and make sure that `Active (x64)` is selected in the "Platform" drop-down (it's Win32 by default). If `x64` is not available in the dropdown, click `[Configuration Manager...]`, and choose `x64` for the platform of your project. If a "Copy from..." dialog opens, click `[OK]` to dismiss it. The program should run in 64-bit mode after a recompile.

Comment: I compiled it on the same computer, perhaps I must include some compiler or linker options. Do you know what options will compile for 64-bit. I am using visual studio 2010. Thanks

Comment: @user2340048 I edited the answer to explain how to compile for x64 in visual studio.

Comment: @user2340048 Great! If the issue is now resolved, consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would let others know that you are no longer actively looking for an improved solution to this problem, and earn you a new badge on stack overflow.